# TFS dotnet restore - Unable to load the service index for source

Tags: tfs, msbuild, nuget-package, feed

I have a package which I added to to TFS feed, I can browse feed in VS 2K17, add the packge to add it to a dotnet project compile correctly and it downloads the pkg, on command line also msbuild t:restore works fine.
In TFS, I am using a 
dotnet restore 
step but it is failing with the following error for the same package

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.500\NuGet.targets(114,5): error :
>   Unable to load the service index for source
>   http://vsalms:8080/tfs/TODOS/_packaging/e475f9ce-1afd-47c9-8aa6-2f0d54948126/nuget/v3/index.json.
>   [C:\agent_work\2\s\lib\CoreFlogger\CoreFlogger.csproj]
>   2018-12-03T14:24:46.6934510Z C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.500\NuGet.targets(114,5): error : The token
>   supplied to the function is invalid
>   [C:\agent_work\2\s\lib\CoreFlogger\CoreFlogger.csproj]

I am not sure which version of nugget it uses as there is no indication in the task. I have downloaded nuget and added its path to the environment, typing nugget in console gives the following
NuGet Version: 4.8.1.5435 but when build fails, I see

Regarding dotnet version, on the commande line when I issue

> dotnet.exe --version
>   2.1.500

In the build ouptut, I see

> 2018-12-03T14:24:38.9211043Z Description : Build, test, package, or
>   publish a dotnet application, or run a custom dotnet command. For
>   package commands, supports NuGet.org and authenticated feeds like
>   Package Management and MyGet. 2018-12-03T14:24:38.9211302Z Version :
>   2.131.0

On the TFS server, I also added a a key in global nuget.config as follows

> 

What is missing? It seems that it is a connection issue but really not able to debug or find out wwhat/where to check

Comment: What version of TFS are you using?

Comment: 2018 update 3 on premise

Comment: Hi Daniel, sorry, in TFS admin I see 16.122.27102.1 (Tfs2018). Sorry for my delaued response, I did not receive an alert when you responded

Comment: Daniel, please ignore my 1st comment, I looked at another TFS (which is for testing purposes.) The TFS having the issues is 16.131.28106.2 (Tfs2018.Update3) @daniel-mann

Comment: I upgraded to 3.1 but getting the exact same error

Comment: Having the exact same problem in DevOps Server 2019.1.1 using the dotnet restore 2.* task

Comment: facing the same issue